# C # infinite loop help basic programming

Tags: c#, infinite-loop, tryparse

I'm in my second quarter of c # programming and i'm working on a POS application. I have my windows form created and I have my basic code done for the first week it was assigned. Now I have to "idiot-proof" my code by making sure that only correct data can be entered. Here's what I have so far:

```
private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declare variables
    double dblSalesTax = 0, dblPrice, dblTax, dblSalesPrice;
    string strItem, strTaxAdded;
    int intQuantity;
    bool diffTest = false;

    //Process user input

    while (!diffTest)
    {
        diffTest = double.TryParse(txtSalesTax.Text, out dblSalesTax);
    }   

    while (dblSalesTax < 0 || dblSalesTax > 25)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid tax.");
        txtSalesTax.Clear();

        diffTest = false;
    }

    intQuantity = Convert.ToInt16(txtQuantity.Text);
    dblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
    dblSalesPrice = dblPrice * intQuantity;
    strItem = cbxItem.Text;
    intQuantity = Convert.ToInt16(txtQuantity.Text);

    dblSubtotal += dblSalesPrice;

    if (chkTaxExempt.Checked)
    {
        dblTax = 0;
        strTaxAdded = "";
    }
    else
    {
        dblTax = dblSalesPrice * dblSalesTax;
        strTaxAdded = "*";
    }

    dblTaxTotal += dblTax;

    lbxTally.Items.Add(strItem + ", " + dblSalesPrice.ToString("C") + strTaxAdded);

    //Reset Form

    txtPrice.Clear();
    txtQuantity.Clear();
    chkTaxExempt.Checked = false;
    cbxItem.Focus();
}


private void btnEndSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dblGrandTotal = dblSubtotal + dblTaxTotal;
    lbxTally.Items.Add("");
    lbxTally.Items.Add("");
    lbxTally.Items.Add("Subtotal: " + dblSubtotal.ToString("C"));
    lbxTally.Items.Add("Tax Total: " + dblTaxTotal.ToString("C"));
    lbxTally.Items.Add("Grand Total: " + dblGrandTotal.ToString("C"));
}

private void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double dblPay, dblChange;

    dblPay = Convert.ToDouble(txtPay.Text);
    dblChange = dblPay - dblGrandTotal;
    lbxTally.Items.Add("");
    lbxTally.Items.Add("Amount Paid: " + dblPay.ToString("C"));
    lbxTally.Items.Add("Change: " + dblChange.ToString("C"));
}
```

Variables being declared beforehand and diffTest being initialized as false.
The assignment is to make sure that the sales tax entered is between 0 and 25 and that they can't enter words or anything else. I thought I did it right but when I run it, I have an infinite loop on my message box and I can't figure out how to get out of it correctly (entering break just gets me out but keeps the input). I have google'd to my hearts content but haven't found a solution but I feel like it's because my code is reusing what's in the text box automatically (I could be very wrong!). Once I get this i'll have to "idiot-proof" my other inputs but I haven't tried yet cause I'm still stuck on this first one. I'm a beginner programming student so any help is appreciated.

Comment: your users will never have the chance to correct their input! Don't do it like this - just do the message-box once (or better display a red label or something with the error near the input! - You know this from  webforms I think) ... and a minor point: we don't usually name variables like `dblSalesTax` - it's really clear that it's a `double` and the methods should never be so big that this convention matters anymore - and of course we can just hover the mouse over it and *see* the type ;)

Comment: Our professor has us name our variables like this to help clarify the type of data being used...interesting though as he stated that "real-world" variables are named in the same manner as well but it would seem that is not the case?

Comment: IMO not in C#/Java - this used to be the case in C/C++ but I stoped doing real world C++ 12years ago so that might have changed as well - just have a look around Github or search for naming conventions if you like

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should change `While` to `If`.

```
private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declare variables
    double dblSalesTax = 0, dblPrice, dblTax, dblSalesPrice;
    string strItem, strTaxAdded;
    int intQuantity;
    bool diffTest = false;

    //Process user input


        //While (!diffTest)
        //{

          diffTest = double.TryParse(txtSalesTax.Text, out dblSalesTax);

        //}   
        // Check if the value gets parsed and is in range, otherwise show error and 
        //exit from this handler
        If (!diffTest || dblSalesTax < 0 || dblSalesTax > 25)  '<--- Change While to If
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid tax.");
            txtSalesTax.Clear();

            diffTest = false;
            return; // Return from here since validation failed
        }

        ... 
        ...
        ...
}
```

Comment: I will try this when I get home from work and let you know if it worked. Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much for the help! After staring for so long i lost track of the return function and confused myself on if and while statements. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while statement there. Change it to:

```
if (dblSalesTax < 0 || dblSalesTax > 25)
```

Because you have there a while loop as soon as you step into that loop you will never get out because your condition will be always true.

Answer (score 0):

May you can try using `Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());` with`await` for the the `task` that has your loop, something like below:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
        () =>
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Begin first task...");
            },  // close first Action

        async () =>
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
                  while (true)
                        {

                         // HERE you are the code you need to be executed in infinite loop

                          await Task.Delay(60000);
                         }
              }, //close second Action

        () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin third task...");
            } //close third Action
        ); //close parallel.invoke

        Console.WriteLine("Returned from Parallel.Invoke");
```